# LUKS + LVM at Install Time

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm, btrfs, luks

I am trying to use the Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS installer to create a disk layout that logically looks like this during installation:

```
/dev/sad
   |
   +-- /dev/sda1 (/boot)
   |
   +-- /dev/sda2 (LUKS)
   |     |
   |     +- SWAP
   |     |
   |     +- / (root)
   |
   |-- [ 60GB free space for SSD over-provisioning ]
```

I chose "Something else" when asked about disk partitioning and I *think* to achieve this that I have to use LVM, like this:

```
/dev/sda
   |
   +-- /dev/sda1 (/boot)
   |
   +-- /dev/sda2 (LUKS)
   |     | 
   |     +-- LVM
   |          |
   |          +- SWAP (logical volume for swap)
   |          |
   |          +- / (logical volume for root)
   |
   |-- [ 60GB free space for SSD over-provisioning ]
```

Basically, I want a **single** LUKS container that contains both SWAP and / (root) partitions so SWAP and root are both encrypted together.

I cannot find any way to set this up in the Ubuntu 14.04.3 installer.  I can create the LUKS container, but it always contains a single partition under it and I can find no way to setup LVM within it.

I tried to setup LUKS and then quit the installer, use the LVM command-line and then go back in and install on the logical volumes, but I got a system that would not boot.

If there is a way to do this with LVM or even without LVM (maybe with btrfs for /boot and /, but not for SWAP since copy-on-write would suck for SWAP), please help.

Comment: I have swap and root on the same LUKS + LVM on my laptop, installed using the default graphical installer. The installer automatically uses LVM on top of LUKS. Is the issue that you can't get it to leave 60 GB of space at the end of the SSD?